# Calling javascript method from from inside object

Tags: javascript, methods, naming

I am struggling with methods in JavaScript.

```
  obj = function(){
    this.getMail = function getMail (){
    }
//Here I would like to run the get mail once but this.getMail() or getMail() wont work
    }


var mail = new obj();
mail.getMail();
```

How do I make the method in a way that I can run it both inside the object and from the outside

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define the function use the name just once, like this:

```
obj = function(){
  this.getMail = function(){
    alert("bob");
  }
}
```

Now you can use `this.getMail()` in there, [you can see a working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/2zTKb/).

Comment: Thanks for the link, really useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Building a robust definition for your object is recommended. Build a prototype for it, then if you ever need two or more, you can make instances of them. I show below how to build a prototype, add methods that call eachother, and how to instantiate the object.

obj = function () {}  //define the empty object

```
obj.prototype.getMail = function () {  
//this is a function on new instances of that object
   //whatever code you like
   return mail;
}

obj.prototype.otherMethod = function () { 
//this is another function that can access obj.getMail via 'this'
    this.getMail();
}

var test = new obj; //make a new instance
test.getMail();     //call the first method
test.otherMethod(); //call the second method (that has access to the first)
```

Comment: Thanks, not familiar with prototype. I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
var obj = function() {

    function getMail() {
        alert('hai!');
    }

    this.getMail = getMail;
    //Here I would like to run the get mail once but this.getMail() or getMail() wont work

    getMail();
}

var mail = new obj();
mail.getMail();
```